# Annoying lines ruining the image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Image Lines Struggle]
I was planning to do a 1920x1080 wallpaper from my favourite musician's cover. Everything was going good so far until I used correction brush which totally ruined my whole work. There are pixelated lines (how do I call these?!) everywhere! They're everywhere, it's very visible when zooming. Using Content-Aware Fill did nothing about it. I beg for help. Sorry if I did something wrong writing this post, i'm a beginner.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Raster images are supposed to be viewed at 100%. If you zoom in on raster images, then you will see pixels.

Comment: It's hard to explain, let me try again.
https://gyazo.com/ce38a59f416a011035bc66625d2284a5
You can see on the screenshot that I recently copied and pasted a part of image.
https://gyazo.com/9ee3aad6bf2fd4c2195155e9f4058f2e
This is what happened after using correction brush, it just blurred the line between these two squares...
https://gyazo.com/1ef6308315a83d6f566cb56eb3d8c10b
...and this is where the problem starts. I wouldn't mind if it was invisible but as you can see it's very visible from far away and it doesn't let me finish my work because of the ugliness.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the seam between two images? Also, there is no tool in Photoshop called a correction brush, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Did you try to use the Stamp tool?

Comment: I am very sorry mister Kerr, I was mentioning this tool: https://gyazo.com/cf642a7c964076667a31e4b07edb203a
In Polish it translates into correcting brush or something like that.

About LeoNas' comment... I never used Stamp tool before, I'll tell you if that will improve anything. Thank you for recommending.

Comment: It's the "Healing Brush".  It's no good for that kind of work. Use the Clone Stamp tool instead.

Comment: I used the Stamp tool like you told me. Everything looks much better now but some parts are still blurry after all. At least it doesn't have these bothering lines anymore, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments, it would appear that you have used the Healing Brush tool.  It's not really effective for that kind of work.  It's better for removing small blemishes like spots.

Use the Clone Stamp Tool instead. Use <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+click to select the clone source, then paint over the seam. Select different clone sources to make it look more random.

See this example

[image]

Note: if the images are on separate layers you will also need to select the option to sample "all layers" in the tool options along the top.

[image]

Comment: Even though I don't even have Photoshop open, I still tried to click away that clone stamp tool info popup. Took a half a second for my brain to figure out it's a gif...

Comment: @Joonas, lol and sigh. Imagine a hammer that told you everyday that it's "handy for hammering nails into wood" .

Comment: "Hi @Wolff, I'm Clippy. It looks like you are using the clone stamp tool. Need assistance with that? Do you perhaps need to clone or stamp things?"

Comment: @Joonas actually I engaged the "rich tool tips" deliberately when recording this GIF, to highlight the clone stamp tool, since the OP is using the Polish version of Photoshop, and obviously I don't know the name for it in Polish. I thought the visual cue would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider another approach. If that texture isn't some magical cult pattern with hidden powers, fill the space with another apparently as dense pattern. Here's only an example:

[image]

Texture is made with Filters >Render > Fibers, adding edge glow effect, scaling to a little bigger size, adjusting curves (=invert, reduce contrast). Layer color matches the color overall and where the new texture and original image meet. The piece of the original image has got a new edge.

Comment: Sorry for being late to the party. Very creative but I think I'll stick to the initial intention. Thanks once again, this was really useful.